# HACER UN INSERT COMPARANDO REGISTROS MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert

tengo dos tablas que son **tempbio3**

[image: descripción tempbio3]

> **biometrico**

[image: descripción biometrico]

> **RESUMEN**

Los datos de tempbio3 van hacer borrados siempre ya que es una tabla temporal, por eso el biometrico_id no sirve como referencia al insertar, es por eso que estaba tomando la fechas como parámetro principal de comparación

> ***Problema***

los datos del tempbio3 tengo que insertarlos a biometrico pero en caso de que los datos ya esten en biometrico no los inserte.

> codigo que elabore

```
Insert into biometrico(PIN,fecha,hora,observacion)(
    select tb3.pin,tb3.fecha,tb3.hora,tb3.observacion 
    from TEMPBIO3 tb3
    join biometrico b on b.biometrico_id=tb3.biometrico_id
    where concat( CAST(b.fecha AS char), " " , CAST(b.hora AS char)) <> 
    concat( CAST(tb3.fecha AS char), " " , CAST(tb3.hora AS char)));
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Además sugiero que edites tu pregunta y añadas cuál es el problema que estás teniendo con el código del `insert` que muestras en la pregunta, si es un error, que incluyas el mensaje exacto de error que tienes.

Answer (score 0):

puedes aplicarle el left join  y después checa si biometrico_id=null

ejemplo:

```
Insert into biometrico(PIN,fecha,hora,observacion)(
    select tb3.pin,tb3.fecha,tb3.hora,tb3.observacion 
    from TEMPBIO3 tb3
    left join biometrico b on concat( CAST(b.fecha AS char), " " , CAST(b.hora AS char)) =
concat( CAST(tb3.fecha AS char), " " , CAST(tb3.hora AS char)))
    where b.biometrico_id is null;
```

Comment: acabo de insertar un pequeño resumen sobre mi problema, mi tabla tempbio3 es una tabla temporal, por eso el biometrico_id no me sirve como parametro de comparación por eso estaba tomando las fechas.

Comment: entonces en el left join solo se compararía las fechas

Comment: si justamente quiero comparar las fechas con esta linea de código  `concat( CAST(b.fecha AS char), " " , CAST(b.hora AS char)) <> 
    concat( CAST(tb3.fecha AS char), " " , CAST(tb3.hora AS char)));` pero no se porque me funciona el operador <> ni != para hacer la comparación, me envía el resultado en blanco